# How do you make those animated intro tutorials/walkthroughs/screens in mobile apps?

Tags: ios, animation

The first time you access a mobile app or when there's an update, there will be a few screens that highlight features in the app (a what's new/tutorial modal). I've seen some of these images animate within the screen. A recent good example I've seen was the MS Office's suite of iPad apps. The images they use look like they are being drawn. To be clear, I am not referring to an animated loading screen when first launching the app. This is usually a modal that shows up when you select a "get started" or "learn more" type of button.

I've tried looking through a couple forums and general searching but I haven't found any best practices (or even info on how). Are these animations a video, an animated image (gif?), a series of moving panes that are uncovering the image in a certain way? I would think the best method for doing this is also cognizant of the file size so as not to bulk up the app size significantly.

Also, is there a common term/name for these intro screens? I've seen some sites use "walkthroughs" but that also refers to product video tutorials occasionally.

Any advice or information is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I have got a code on GitHub that does a similar job. 
Here's the link: https://github.com/karanthakakr04/Walkthrough-Demo.git
I hope it serves your need. Also there's this reference tutorial if someone needs it: https://youtu.be/tNCsQe5vfRk

Answer (score 1):

you could do a video, or a fullscreen image.  You could also do something like create a UIView for each step of your walkthrough and then put the inside of a scrollview and let the user flip through them like in a photo app.  You could do something like a PageViewController as well.  Or you could get really fancy and have view controllers with animation code and all the like.

As for how to decide when to show the walkthrough NSUserdefaults is a great tool.

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasShowWalkthroughForVersion1"]) {
    //save that we've show the walkthrough in user defaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasShownWalkthroughForVersion1"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    //show walkthrough
    ....
}
```

Comment: I have got a code on GitHub that does a similar job. 
Here's the link: https://github.com/karanthakakr04/Walkthrough-Demo.git
I hope it serves your need. Also there's this reference tutorial if someone needs it: https://youtu.be/tNCsQe5vfRk

Answer (score 1):

For iOS you can use local storage to detect if the user is running the app for the first time for example this piece of code plays a movie the first time the user runs the app

```
NSString *bundleVersion = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey];
NSString *appFirstStartOfVersionKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"first_start_%@", bundleVersion];

    NSNumber *alreadyStartedOnVersion = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:appFirstStartOfVersionKey];
    if(!alreadyStartedOnVersion || [alreadyStartedOnVersion boolValue] == NO) {
        // first start of the current version

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"playMovie"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:appFirstStartOfVersionKey];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        [self performSelector:@selector(showVideoThenLaunch) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];

    }else{
        UIView *statusBg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,20.0)];
        statusBg.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.window addSubview:statusBg];
    }
```

Animating a series of images - you can set a series of Images for a UIImageView, in this example a series of images are repeated

```
// animation on home screen
bearPaw = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 270, 254, 141.5)]; 
// load all the frames of our animation

bearPaw.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"swipe1"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"swipe2"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"swipe12"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"swipe13"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"swipe14"], nil];

// all frames will execute in 1.75 seconds
bearPaw.animationDuration = 1.0;
// repeat the annimation forever
bearPaw.animationRepeatCount = 3;
// start animating
[bearPaw startAnimating];
// add the animation view to the main window 
[self.view addSubview:bearPaw];
```

Comment: I have got a code on GitHub that does a similar job. 
Here's the link: https://github.com/karanthakakr04/Walkthrough-Demo.git
I hope it serves your need. Also there's this reference tutorial if someone needs it: https://youtu.be/tNCsQe5vfRk